# ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4.Required by: com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.1.0

Tags: android, maven, gradle, butterknife, android-workmanager

While integrating **`WorkManager`** in my Application, I updated my app settings as follows:

```
androidMinSdkVersion = 15
androidTargetSdkVersion = 28
androidCompileSdkVersion = 28
androidBuildToolsVersion = "28.0.0"
```

Due to version upgrade to 28 I had to update gradle too.

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

**Project.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            // Gradle 4.1 and higher include support for Google's Maven repo using
            // the google() method. And you need to include this repo to download
            // Android Gradle plugin 3.0.0 or higher.
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }

        dependencies {

            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
            classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

  allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }        
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Due to all these changes(mainly WorkManger), I had to (was forced to) upgrade the butterknife library version to 9.0.0 at least. 
So I updated it as follows in my **app.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.1.0'
    }
}
```

But whenever I try to clean-build I keep getting following error in logcat.

```
ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.jar
Required by:
    project :_btn_payment > com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.1.0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide full **project.gradle**

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.1.0'` to `Project.gradle`

Answer (score -1):

butterknife 10.x only supports AndroidX-enabled builds.
You will changed to version 9.0.0

From gradle gradle plugin 3.0 apt has deprecated,delete `classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'`

library build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0'
    }
}
```